# rename columns on a list of dataframes respect to names of df list with tidy functions

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, tidyverse

I would like using tidyverse to rename some columns
in a list with Tibbles respect to the names of the elements I
use in a map function call.
example:

```
c("star","wars") %>% 
set_names() %>% 
map(~starwars %>% 
mutate(col_1 = .x) %>% #this as an example for the use of other functions that I have to use in the real data
select(col_1 ,everything()) %>% 
rename_at(vars(name:eye_color), list(~str_c(.,"_",.x)))) <- the issue
```

The result:

```
$star
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_name height_height mass_mass hair_color_hair~
   <chr> <chr>             <int>     <dbl> <chr>           
 1 star  Luke Sky~           172        77 blond           
 2 star  C-3PO               167        75 NA              
 3 star  R2-D2                96        32 NA              
 4 star  Darth Va~           202       136 none            
 5 star  Leia Org~           150        49 brown           
 6 star  Owen Lars           178       120 brown, grey     
 7 star  Beru Whi~           165        75 brown           
 8 star  R5-D4                97        32 NA              
 9 star  Biggs Da~           183        84 black           
10 star  Obi-Wan ~           182        77 auburn, white   
# ... with 77 more rows, and 10 more variables:
#   skin_color_skin_color <chr>, eye_color_eye_color <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>,
#   species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
#   starships <list>

$wars
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_name height_height mass_mass hair_color_hair~
   <chr> <chr>             <int>     <dbl> <chr>           
 1 wars  Luke Sky~           172        77 blond           
 2 wars  C-3PO               167        75 NA              
 3 wars  R2-D2                96        32 NA              
 4 wars  Darth Va~           202       136 none            
 5 wars  Leia Org~           150        49 brown           
 6 wars  Owen Lars           178       120 brown, grey     
 7 wars  Beru Whi~           165        75 brown           
 8 wars  R5-D4                97        32 NA              
 9 wars  Biggs Da~           183        84 black           
10 wars  Obi-Wan ~           182        77 auburn, white   
# ... with 77 more rows, and 10 more variables:
#   skin_color_skin_color <chr>, eye_color_eye_color <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>,
#   species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
#   starships <list>
```

> What I want create:

```
$star
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_star height_star mass_star hair_color_star~
   <chr> <chr>             <int>     <dbl> <chr>           
 1 star  Luke Sky~           172        77 blond           
 2 star  C-3PO               167        75 NA              
 3 star  R2-D2                96        32 NA              
 4 star  Darth Va~           202       136 none            
 5 star  Leia Org~           150        49 brown           
 6 star  Owen Lars           178       120 brown, grey     
 7 star  Beru Whi~           165        75 brown           
 8 star  R5-D4                97        32 NA              
 9 star  Biggs Da~           183        84 black           
10 star  Obi-Wan ~           182        77 auburn, white   
# ... with 77 more rows, and 10 more variables:
#   skin_color_star <chr>, eye_color_star <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>,
#   species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
#   starships <list>

$wars
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_wars height_wars mass_wars hair_color_wars~
   <chr> <chr>             <int>     <dbl> <chr>           
 1 wars  Luke Sky~           172        77 blond           
 2 wars  C-3PO               167        75 NA              
 3 wars  R2-D2                96        32 NA              
 4 wars  Darth Va~           202       136 none            
 5 wars  Leia Org~           150        49 brown           
 6 wars  Owen Lars           178       120 brown, grey     
 7 wars  Beru Whi~           165        75 brown           
 8 wars  R5-D4                97        32 NA              
 9 wars  Biggs Da~           183        84 black           
10 wars  Obi-Wan ~           182        77 auburn, white   
# ... with 77 more rows, and 10 more variables:
#   skin_color_wars <chr>, eye_color_wars <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>,
#   species <chr>, films <list>, vehicles <list>,
#   starships <list>
```

For some reason, rename_at looks at ".x" as "." coming from the name of the columns and not
from the map.
How could it be possible to make use of .x of the map function?

Comment: I've run into instances where the formula interface in `map()` got so tricky it was easier to use an anonymous function.  So instead of `~starwars %>% mutate(col_1 = .x) ...`  you'd have, e.g., `function(x) starwars %>% mutate(col_1 = x)...`.

Comment: Looks like you could also keep the tilde for the overall `map()` but use an anonymous function within the `rename_at()` list: `list(function(x) str_c(x,"_",.x))`

Comment: Yeap, that's what I was trying to do but without the "writing" of anonymous function.
Anyway, as long as it works, and good old way goes well, better use it.
Do we have an answer as why it happens that issue in rename?

Comment: The reason it's not working the way you expect is because `.x` refers to the same object as `.` within the final lambda function created by `~`. The symbols `.`, `..1`, and `.x` all refer to the same object.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks, so there's the way with the anonym fun do it only?
aosmith if you could put it as an answer so as to accept, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One workaround is to use an anonymous function inside `rename_at()` instead of a formula to avoid the issue of `.x` and `.` referring to the same object.  You could also use an anonymous function for the `map()` function and the tilde in `rename_at()`.

```
c("star","wars") %>% 
     set_names() %>% 
     map(~starwars %>% 
              mutate(col_1 = .x) %>% 
              select(col_1 ,everything()) %>% 
              rename_at(vars(name:eye_color), function(var) str_c(var, "_", .x)))

$star
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_star height_star mass_star hair_color_star skin_color_star
   <chr> <chr>           <int>     <dbl> <chr>           <chr>          
 1 star  Luke Sky~         172        77 blond           fair           
 2 star  C-3PO             167        75 NA              gold           
 3 star  R2-D2              96        32 NA              white, blue    
 4 star  Darth Va~         202       136 none            white          
 5 star  Leia Org~         150        49 brown           light          
 6 star  Owen Lars         178       120 brown, grey     light          
 7 star  Beru Whi~         165        75 brown           light          
 8 star  R5-D4              97        32 NA              white, red     
 9 star  Biggs Da~         183        84 black           light          
10 star  Obi-Wan ~         182        77 auburn, white   fair           
# ... with 77 more rows, and 9 more variables: eye_color_star <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>, species <chr>,
#   films <list>, vehicles <list>, starships <list>

$wars
# A tibble: 87 x 15
   col_1 name_wars height_wars mass_wars hair_color_wars skin_color_wars
   <chr> <chr>           <int>     <dbl> <chr>           <chr>          
 1 wars  Luke Sky~         172        77 blond           fair           
 2 wars  C-3PO             167        75 NA              gold           
 3 wars  R2-D2              96        32 NA              white, blue    
 4 wars  Darth Va~         202       136 none            white          
 5 wars  Leia Org~         150        49 brown           light          
 6 wars  Owen Lars         178       120 brown, grey     light          
 7 wars  Beru Whi~         165        75 brown           light          
 8 wars  R5-D4              97        32 NA              white, red     
 9 wars  Biggs Da~         183        84 black           light          
10 wars  Obi-Wan ~         182        77 auburn, white   fair           
# ... with 77 more rows, and 9 more variables: eye_color_wars <chr>,
#   birth_year <dbl>, sex <chr>, gender <chr>, homeworld <chr>, species <chr>,
#   films <list>, vehicles <list>, starships <list>
```

For posterity, `rename_at()` has been superseded by `rename_with()` in **dplyr** version 1.0.0 (but is not going away).  The `rename_with()` code would look like:

```
... %>%
     rename_with(.fn = function(var) str_c(var, "_", .x), .cols = name:eye_color))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using @aosmith's answer is to force expression of a defuse expression:

```
library(rlang)
c("star","wars") %>% 
  set_names() %>% 
  map(~starwars %>% 
        mutate(col_1 = .x) %>%
        select(col_1 ,everything()) %>% 
        rename_at(vars(name:eye_color), list(~str_c(.,"_",!!quo(.x)))))
```

I think the anonymous function with different symbols is definitely the safer and clearer approach, but this is intended to show it is possible.

Comment: Ah! so using the quasi-quotation  is the way to do it more tidy.
advanced tidyverse course is need it I guess :)